# SSLHandshakeException dynamic web project java

Tags: java, soap, wicket, handshake, preemptive

In my Wicket application I would like to send data to a wsdl-endpoint with soap. To accomplish this, I made a dynamic web project in Eclipse (with Axis2). I get an error while connecting to the endpoint. The error is:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

The endpoint expects a username and password, with a preemptive connection.

This is my code:

```
Deliver deliver = new Deliver();

XmlDataList dataList = new XmlDataList();
dataList.addXmlData(XML);   
deliver.setXmlDataList(dataList);
Stubstub = new Stub();

Authenticator basicAuthenticator = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
List<String> schemes= new ArrayList<String>();
authSchemes.add(Authenticator.BASIC);
basicAuthenticator.setAuthSchemes(schemes); 
basicAuthenticator.setUsername("UName");
basicAuthenticator.setPassword("Pwd");
basicAuthenticator.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);

stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuthenticator);
```

How can I set the preemptive conditions for connecting to a wsdl (https)? Can someone explain to me how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your endpoint uses a probably self-signed certificate. You have to add this certificate to your local keystore in order to accept it. See the following question: [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)